# How to display relative/absolute date/time selection?

Tags: dates, time, first-impression

What is the appropriate way to present relative vs absolute date selection to the user?

e.g.

In [*increment/decrement numeric field*] [*mins/hours dropdown*]

On [*calendar-selector*], [*time-selector*]

Comment: Your ideas seem nice solutions to me. Integrating the values in sentences makes the GUI feel more talking. But I would still keep highlights on the time/date to minimize focus times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ***ABSOLUTE DATE SELECTION***

---

Your absolute date selection doesn't need any other changes; that's straight forward:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuHVMf.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

## ***RELATIVE DATE SELECTION***

---

When it comes to the relative date selection, I would change 2 things:

1. The blank field should probably be a spinner control that increments and decrements integer values.
2. I would add a link to the side that would allow you to add another date part.  It would then add another spinner control and drop down with the remaining available date parts.  This would give the users a more precise granularity.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyjSSy.png)</sup>